# How can I create a RSA public key in PEM format from an RSA modulus?

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, m2crypto

I have the modulus of an RSA public key. I want to use this public key with the [Python library "M2Crypto",](http://wiki.osafoundation.org/bin/view/Projects/MeTooCrypto) but it requires a public key in PEM format.

Thus, I have to convert the RSA modulus to a PEM file.

The modulus can be found [here.](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/118040/)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The M2Crypto library has [a way to reconstruct a public key.](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.RSA-module.html#new_pub_key) You need to know the public exponent, `e` (often 65337 for RSA keys, but other numbers such as 3 or 17 have been used), and the modulus, `n` (which is the 512-bit number provided in the question). Note that the docs describe the length-encoded format used for `e` and `n`.

Once the public key has been reconstructed, it can be [saved into a file](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.RSA.RSA_pub-class.html#save_key) and used again later without the hassle of conversion.

Comment: No, I just want to encrypt messages with a python library (m2crypt) instead of the js library.And I want to use the key but as you can see, the rsa key I found is not same as a ssh public key file.

Comment: It's not a joke.The question is simple, I've got a public RSA key and want to use it with a python library that does not support the format of the public key.I need to convert it.

Comment: Okay then, you need to provide the public exponent of the key. For normal RSA keys, this is often 65537. But for a tiny 512-bit key, I'm not sure if the same exponent would be used.

Comment: @erickson, I'm having similar troubles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367072/m2crypto-import-keys-from-non-standard-file. I have the modulus and exponent in a file as hex values. I can read them as longs in python or as hex strings, but I don't know how to create a public key with them. M2Crypto is throwing all sorts of errors on padding and things.